# ui-router get Http Status Code when state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to get the Http request status code (200,301,404)
and manually do the next step.

How do I get the **status code** in ui-router **state change**?

==update==

When using ui-router to get ui-view, we will get 200 text/html to render.

But I want to check if the respond is 301 redirect url

What should I do on this

==update==

I found there is a paragraph

```
A response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success status and will result
in the success callback being called. Note that if the response is a redirect, 
XMLHttpRequest will transparently follow it, meaning that the error callback will not be 
called for such responses.
```

from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Is the the answer? (auto redirect url)

Comment: The question is not clear

Comment: I going to make a wild guess and assume you are asking about the response code when fetching a ui-view template?  If it's a redirect, you shouldn't have to manually do anything.  If you need to catch 404, etc, then I  suggest reading about http interceptors in angular.

Answer (score 3):

No. HTTP status codes are for HTTP messages, which come from servers. They have nothing to do with client-side routing frameworks.